# Sort by value in json array in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I have table called `foo` like this :

```
create table foo
(
    Id Int,
    Description Nvarchar(Max)
)
```

I have json in array in `Description` like this:

```
[
   {
      "name":"a",
      "date":"2021-03-01"
   },
   {
      "name":"b",
      "date":"2021-03-02"
   }
]
```

I want sort foo table by max date in json list - something like this:

```
select * 
from foo
order by json_value(Description, '$.date')
```

but this query does not work.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The example data you've given looks like a single row with a JSON blob. How should a single row be sorted? Please edit your question to show the output you are expecting.

Comment: Tank For answer, You are exactly right, If I had an object in json,This query worked, but I have an array of objects inside json,I need a query to find the largest date in each row from the json list, and my total output is sorted by the largest date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to parse the stored JSON with `OPENJSON()` and find the max date:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    Id Int,
    Description Nvarchar(Max)
)
INSERT INTO foo (Id, Description)
VALUES
   (1, N'[{"name":"a","date":"2021-03-01"},{"name":"b","date":"2021-03-02"}]'),
   (2, N'[{"name":"a","date":"2021-03-11"},{"name":"b","date":"2021-03-12"}]')
```

Statement:

```
SELECT Id, Description
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM foo f
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT MAX([date]) AS [Date]
      FROM OPENJSON(f.Description) WITH ([date] nvarchar(10) '$.date')
   ) j
) t
ORDER BY TRY_CONVERT(date, [Date], 23)
```

Result:

```
Id  Description
1   [{"name":"a","date":"2021-03-01"},{"name":"b","date":"2021-03-02"}]
2   [{"name":"a","date":"2021-03-11"},{"name":"b","date":"2021-03-12"}]
```